# Extracting information from DBpedia

Tags: python, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I am working on a project and I want to make use of DBpedia. I have few hundreds of DBpedia links like

- http://dbpedia.org/page/Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency

What is better use of time:

- to crawl those pages and extract the information that I want?
- to query the data with a SPARQL query from Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, note that the URI identifying the DBpedia resource is not

- http://dbpedia.org/page/Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency

with *page*, but

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency

with *resource*.  Second, it will be *much* faster to retrieve information using SPARQL.  SPARQL is a query language for RDF, and you're looking to get RDF data.  All you need to do in SPARQL to get information about FEMA is a describe query:

```
describe
  dbpedia:Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=describe%20dbpedia%3aFederal_Emergency_Management_Agency&format=text/turtle&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Describe queries can describe multiple resources, so you can do, for instance:

```
describe
  dbpedia:Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency
  dbpedia:Mount_Monadnock
  # more resources...
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=describe%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aFederal_Emergency_Management_Agency%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aMount_Monadnock&format=text/turtle&timeout=30000&debug=on)

If you only want certain information about some resources, you can still do something similar with select or construct queries, using `values` and programmatically injecting the resources you're interested in:

```
select ?label where { 
  values ?resource {
    dbpedia:Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency # put your values in here and
    dbpedia:Mount_Monadnock                     # ?resource will be bound to each
  }
  ?resource rdfs:label ?label .
  filter( langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?label%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20values%20?resource%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpedia%3aFederal_Emergency_Management_Agency%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpedia%3aMount_Monadnock%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20?resource%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28%20lang%28?label%29,%20%22EN%22%20%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

You can also use a construct to get those triples in a model:

```
construct {
  ?resource rdfs:label ?label 
}
where { 
  values ?resource {
    dbpedia:Federal_Emergency_Management_Agency
    dbpedia:Mount_Monadnock
  }
  ?resource rdfs:label ?label .
  filter( langMatches( lang(?label), "EN" ))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=construct%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?resource%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20values%20?resource%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpedia%3aFederal_Emergency_Management_Agency%0D%0A%20%20%20%20dbpedia%3aMount_Monadnock%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20?resource%20rdfs%3alabel%20?label%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28%20lang%28?label%29,%20%22EN%22%20%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text/turtle&timeout=30000&debug=on)